# change address of a website

Tags: python, web

I want to have information about many persons. 
I have these informations on the website www.wats4u.com. .
I have the firstname and the name of these persons in a document exel.

For the moment I have the code :

```
import urllib 
page = urllib.urlopenbegin('https://www.wats4u.com/annuaire-alumni?lastname=algan&firstname=michel&scholl=All&class=All&=rechercher')
strpage = page.read()
sock.close()
print htmlSource
```

And I would like a code more like that :

```
page = urllib.urlopenbegin('https://www.wats4u.com/annuaire-alumni?lastname= + name + &firstname= + firstname + &scholl=All&class=All&=rechercher')
```

I have the name and the firstname in a document exel "test.xlsx"( approximately 5000 people).

What do I need to change or add in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
url = 'https://www.wats4u.com/annuaire-alumni?lastname={}&firstname={}&scholl=All&class=All&=rechercher'
firstname = 'algan'
lastname = 'michel'
page = urllib.urlopenbegin(url.format(firstname, lastname))
```

Comment: Thank you for help. 

But your answer work just for the exemple "Michel ALGAN".

I would like a code that works for the 5000 names.

We can find the 5000 names in a document exel "test.xlsx".

Comment: @pong74 Of course, this is just an example. You will have to look up how to read the other names from Excel and incorporate that with my answer.